# Why don't I get a default APA-abstract and appendix?

Tags: appendices, apa-style, abstract

I'm sorry, I'm still very new to latex. 
I'm writing a psychology report right now and I need to write an abstract. I guess the right setting for abstracts in the APA format are already included in the apa6 package, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The abstract appears as random text and doesn't have the title "Abstract", which it should have. I also can't make my own title, since i can't center text somehow. The same goes for the appendix at the end.

```
\documentclass[man, apacite, floatsintext, 12pt, donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\title{xxx}
\author{xxx}
\affiliation{xxx}
\date{xxx}

\shorttitle{xxx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This should be my abstract
\end{abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\begin{appendix}
\includepdf[pages=1-2]{xxx.pdf} 

\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the standard classes, in `apa6` the abstract should be the argument to `\abstract`:

```
\documentclass[man, apacite, floatsintext, 12pt, donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\title{xxx}
\author{xxx}
\affiliation{xxx}
\date{xxx}
\shorttitle{xxx}

\abstract{%
  This should be my abstract%
}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{AAA}
some text

\section{BBB}
some text

\section{CCC}
some text

\end{document}
```

As for the appendix, LaTeX by default has no `appendix` environment, but just an `\appendix` declaration (no argument) that should be issued when the appendix starts; `apa6` is no exception.

An `appendix` environment is available with the package with the same name, though. I don't think you should load it with `apa6`, but you can check its documentation: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/appendix/appendix.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much egreg, you really helped me a lot. Is it the same for the appendix?

Comment: @Elisa There is no `appendix` environment. Just issue `\appendix` where you want to start it.